# HTML5 TextBox Type=date causes reformatting of date string?

Tags: asp.net, html, date, textbox

**QUESTIONS**

Why is `type="date"` reformatting my date string?

*(From what I have read type="date" writes string as YYYY-MM-DD but this still doen't seem to output what is expected).*

How can `type="date"` be formatted to desired output?

*(Type date is required for touchpad keyboards).*

---

**TYPE:TEXT**

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" ID="txtDate" runat="Server" Text="13/02/2014"/>
```

**OUTPUTS**

`13/02/2014`

```
<input type="text" value="13/02/2014">
```

---

**TYPE: DATE**

```
<asp:TextBox type="date" ID="txtDate" runat="Server" Text="13/02/2014"/>
```

**OUTPUTS**

`2/1/2015`

```
<input type="text" value="2/1/2015">
```

---

Comment: Did you try using the date format as  yyyy-mm-dd ?

Comment: @Amitd Yes no luck. Also just tried : Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")).ToString("d")

Comment: It's going to be easier to tell what is being done to the HTML 5 date input if you show us the HTML 5 source instead of the ASP.NET source that generates it.

Comment: @Quentin see edits above. output shows no reason for this to occur.

Comment: @DreamTeK — Oooh, so the problem is that the ASP.NET isn't generating what you wanted? I thought you meant the browser was munging the date.

Comment: Quentin is right, the browser just does what you asked for. Try to get the date in the format described by the answers below.

Comment: Are we saying that type=date cannot be used unless format is yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: That is what the specification says. The browser decides how to show it to the user.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks for the input. That kind of makes it useless doesn't it?

Comment: No. The point is that the operating system knows best how to format it (using your regional settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why is type="date" reformatting my date string?**

When using type="date" the date **must** be inserted in the format **yyyy-mm-dd** as per the specifications mentioned by Patrick below.

---

**How can type="date" be formatted to desired output?**

The date output will then be displayed to the user based on the users browser and their calendar settings.

**e.g** in my case I use UK calendar so if **yyyy-mm-dd** goes in **dd-mm-yyyy** will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 input date expects the date in the [RFC3339 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339):

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qF2mz/). It shows:

```
02/14/2014
```

for

```
<input type="date" value="2014-02-14" />
```

Comment: Thanks I already noted the standards are yyyy-mm-dd. But does this mean I cannot use type=date AND format the date to desired output?

Comment: No. Not according to the specs.

Comment: More thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry Patrick I had to leave. Yes I now understand how it works and have added notes above.

Comment: @DreamTeK: Can I help you with anything more?